# Eclipse UML2: obtain value of a property defined in a profile

Tags: eclipse, uml, profile, emf, papyrus

I'm new to eclipse UML2 and get stuck in the following problem.

I defined a profile with two stereotypes: ServiceRequest and TransitionEdge. ServiceRequest extends the Action metaclass with two additional properties (cpu, memory), and TransitionEdge extends the ActivityEdge metaclass with the additional property called "probability". All these properties are of type float defined as a PrimitiveType.

The I created an activity diagram that have the profile and stereotypes applied. In the activity diagram, each edge is a TransitionEdge defined in the profile, and a value has been assigned to the probability property.

Having the profile and the activity model, I use the following Java code to load them.

```
// Load the profile
URI profileUri = URI.createURI(PROFILE_NAME);
ResourceSet profileSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
profileSet.getPackageRegistry().put(UMLPackage.eNS_URI, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
profileSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);
profileSet.createResource(profileUri);
Resource profileResource = profileSet.getResource(profileUri, true);
Profile profile = (Profile)EcoreUtil.getObjectByType(profileResource.getContents(), UMLPackage.Literals.PROFILE);
Profile sopraProfile = (Profile)profile.getOwnedMember(PROFILE_NAME);
Stereotype serviceRequestStereotype = (Stereotype)sopraProfile.getOwnedMember(STEREOTYPE_SERVICE_REQUEST); 
Stereotype transitionEdgeStereotype = (Stereotype)sopraProfile.getOwnedMember(STEREOTYPE_TRANSITION_EDGE); 

// Load the model
URI modelUri = URI.createURI(MODEL_NAME);
ResourceSet modelSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
modelSet.getPackageRegistry().put(UMLPackage.eNS_URI, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
modelSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);
modelSet.createResource(modelUri);
Resource modelResource = modelSet.getResource(modelUri, true);
Model model = (Model)EcoreUtil.getObjectByType(modelResource.getContents(), UMLPackage.Literals.MODEL);

EList<Element> elements = model.getOwnedElements();
for(Element e : elements){
     if(e instanceof Activity){
    Activity activity = (Activity)e;
    EList<ActivityEdge> edges = activity.getEdges();
    for(ActivityEdge edge : edges){
        System.out.println(edge.getValue(transitionEdgeStereotype, "probability"));
    }
     }
}
```

An exception is thrown when the getValue method is called upon an element. 
The following is the error message:

```
org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.PropertyImpl@7a6d6a3f (name: base_ActivityEdge, visibility: <unset>) (isLeaf: false) (isStatic: false) (isOrdered: false, isUnique: true, isReadOnly: false) (aggregation: none, isDerived: false, isDerivedUnion: false, isID: false)

org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.PropertyImpl@255a8ce4 (name: probability, visibility: public) (isLeaf: false) (isStatic: false) (isOrdered: false, isUnique: true, isReadOnly: false) (aggregation: none, isDerived: false, isDerivedUnion: false, isID: false)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.StereotypeImpl@442f4161 (name: TransitionEdge, visibility: <unset>) (isLeaf: false, isAbstract: false, isFinalSpecialization: false) (isActive: false)
    at org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.operations.ElementOperations.getValue(ElementOperations.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.ElementImpl.getValue(ElementImpl.java:296)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:68)
```

I couldn't figure out what was going on. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

The Element.getValue(...) method expects the actual Stereotype instance to be passed, that is used with the model.

In the first block, you are retrieving your Stereotype instance from a separate ResourceSet than the one used for the model in the second block. Consequently, the profile is loaded a second time while loading your model and another Stereotype instance is created. You need to pass that one to Element.getValue(...).

This is the safest way to do it:

```
Activity activity = ...
Stereotype transitionEdgeStereotype = 
    activity.getAppliedStereotype(STEREOTYPE_TRANSITION_EDGE);
if (transitionEdgeStereotype != null) {
    System.out.println(edge.getValue(transitionEdgeStereotype, "probability"));
}
```

**Edit:** In this case, STEREOTYPE_TRANSITION_EDGE needs to be the full qualified name of the stereotype including the profile name, e.g. ServiceProfile::TransitionEdge.

Comment: That works perfectly. I get the stereotype from the model and then pass it to the getValue method. Thanks!!